# Django context processor not sending data

Tags: django, django-templates

I created *context_processors.py* in my main app folder and am using the following code in this file:

```
from notifications.models import Notification

def get_notifications(request):
    print("In get notifs")
    notifications = ""
    try:
        user = request.user
        notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=user)
    except:
        pass

    return {'notifications': notifications}
```

Defined this in my *settings.py* as:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ('<app_name>.context_processors.get_notifications',)
```

(I put the name of the application in <app_name>)

I am then using the context preprocessor in a navbar partial:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" id="notification-dropdown">
  {% if notifications %}                                                                     
    Notifications!
  {% else %}
    No notifications
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

But I have noticed that the *notifications* in the navbar partial is always empty. I also haven't seen an output from the print statement that I defined in the *context_processors.py*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'<app_name>.context_processors.get_notifications'
```

Since I had defined the templates in a separate folder, the above context processor was supposed to be defined in settings.py under Templates -> OPTIONS -> context_processors, instead of having it defined separately.

So in settings.py it would look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug', 
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                '<app_name>.context_processors.get_notifications'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```